# macOS, Visual Studio Community: How to change indentation/format settings

Tags: format, visual-studio-mac

How does one change format settings (namely indentation size) in Visual Studio Community on macOS? Answers say to go to `Tools > Options` but there's no `Options` option in my Tools menu. If I recall it's somewhere in `Preferences > Text Editor` but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.

`Preferences > Source Code > Code Formatting`, choose your language and see `Whitespace` options in the `Text Style` tab.

You can use `SHIFT` + `CMD` + `L` to reformat existing files individually.